# Unrecognized option: --deduplicate=address with Emacs-notmuch

Tags: emacs

Recently after un update of emacs-notmuch I get this error 

`Unrecognized option: --deduplicate=address
command: notmuch address --format\=sexp --format-version\=2 --output\=recipients --deduplicate\=address from\:enrico.pirani\@gmail.com\ or\ from\:enrico.pirani\@pec.it
exit status: 1
stderr:
Unrecognized option: --deduplicate=address`

whenever I try to search for an address in my bddb. I use notmuch version 0.20.2 with emacs 24.5.1 on OSX 10.9

Answer (score 0):

The notmuch-emacs interface is intimately tied with the notmuch command-line interface, and they will need to have compatible versions, preferrably the same. You're using a newer version of the notmuch-emacs interface than the cli.

`M-x notmuch-hello-versions RET` in emacs will show you the versions.

Typically, you'd see this after installing notmuch-emacs from MELPA, and notmuch cli from the package manager.